# How do I lazily transform a list into this type?

Tags: haskell, lazy-evaluation, dependent-type, existential-type, continuation-passing

Consider this `Vect` type:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs, DataKinds, KindSignatures, RankNTypes #-}

import Data.Kind (Type)

data Nat = Zero | Succ Nat

data Vect :: Nat -> Type -> Type where
  Nil :: Vect 'Zero a
  Cons :: a -> Vect n a -> Vect ('Succ n) a
```

I'd like to write a function that takes a list and lazily transforms it to this type. Since the length obviously isn't known, we need to use an existential. My first attempt at this used CPS and a rank-2 type to emulate one:

```
listToVect1 :: [a] -> (forall n. Vect n a -> b) -> b
listToVect1 [] f = f Nil
listToVect1 (x:xs) f = listToVect1 xs (f . Cons x)
```

However, this isn't lazy. This is just a foldl (though written as explicit recursion because actually using `foldl` would require impredicativity), so `f` won't start running until it's gone all the way to the end of the list.

I can't think of a way to do CPS in a right-associative manner, so I tried again, this time with a wrapper type instead:

```
data ArbitraryVect a = forall n. ArbitraryVect (Vect n a)

nil :: ArbitraryVect a
nil = ArbitraryVect Nil

cons :: a -> ArbitraryVect a -> ArbitraryVect a
cons x (ArbitraryVect xs) = ArbitraryVect (Cons x xs)

listToVect2 :: [a] -> ArbitraryVect a
listToVect2 = foldr cons nil
```

The problem with this attempt is that I have to use `data` rather than `newtype` (or I get `A newtype constructor cannot have existential type variables`), and I need to pattern-match strictly in `cons` (or I get `An existential or GADT data constructor cannot be used inside a lazy (~) pattern`), so it doesn't return anything until it's through the entire list.

I don't have any other ideas for how to do this. Is this even possible? If so, how? If not, why not?

Answer (score 7):

This is going to be an unsatisfying answer, but I'm going to post it anyway.

---

I don't think this is technically possible, because the head of the result should contain the type `n`, and types cannot be lazily constructed. They're sort of "ephemeral", don't really exist at runtime as such, but *logically* they have to be fully known.

(I am not 100% sure the above is correct though)

---

However, if you really need to do this, you can cheat. Observe that the polymorphic continuation doesn't actually know anything about `n`. The only thing it can possibly find out about `n` is whether it's a `Zero` or `Succ`, but even that is not actually encoded at runtime in any way. Instead, it gets inferred from whichever constructor of `Vect` matches during pattern match. This means that, at runtime, we don't actually have to pass in the correct type for `n`. Sure, the compiler will get anxious during compilation if it can't prove the type is right, but we can convince it to shut up with `unsafeCoerce`:

```
listToVect1 :: [a] -> (forall n. Vect n a -> b) -> b
listToVect1 xs f = f $ go xs
  where
    go :: [a] -> Vect Zero a
    go [] = Nil
    go (x:xs) = unsafeCoerce $ Cons x (go xs)
```

Here, the second line of `go` constructs a `Vect (Succ Zero) a`, but then erases its `n` component to `Zero`. This happens at every step, so the ultimate result is always `Vect Zero a`. This result is then passed to the continuation, which is none the wiser, because it doesn't care.

When the continuation later tries to match on `Vect`'s constructors, it works fine, because the constructors have been instantiated correctly in the right order, reflecting the correct shape of the vector, and by extension, the correct shape of `n`.

This works, try it:

```
vectLen :: Vect n a -> Int
vectLen Nil = 0
vectLen (Cons _ xs) = 1 + vectLen xs

toList :: Vect n a -> [a]
toList Nil = []
toList (Cons a xs) = a : toList xs

main :: IO ()
main = do
  print $ listToVect1 [1,2,3] vectLen        -- prints 3
  print $ listToVect1 [] vectLen             -- prints 0
  print $ listToVect1 [1,2,3,4,5] vectLen    -- prints 5

  print $ listToVect1 [1,2,3] toList         -- prints [1,2,3]
  print $ listToVect1 ([] :: [Int]) toList   -- prints []
  print $ listToVect1 [1,2,3,4,5] toList     -- prints [1,2,3,5]
```

---

Of course, the above is fragile. It relies (to an extent) on some lower-level knowledge. If this is not just a curiosity exercise, I would rather go back and rethink the original problem that lead you to this.

But for what it's worth, this technique of "hiding ugliness by hand-waving" is in a relatively common use in lower-level libraries.